# Show HTML tooltip hints for JSX in VSCode

Tags: html, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

When hovering above a JSX element, VSCode shows the following tooltip:

[image]

However, I think it'd be more useful/informational (particularly for less common HTML elements) to show the regular HTML VSCode tooltip:

[image]

Is this possible to do within JSX files?